# When I add setOnItemSelectedListener to Gallery in Android state selector stops working. Do you know to avoid it?

Tags: android, image-gallery

I have very simple Gallery with Images and I have XML file with selector for various states. It works perfectly (selected has blue background, rest - red one) until I add setOnItemSelectedListener. Then state selectors stops change background of selected item. Just show all backgrounds as unselected. Obviously, Listener overtakes layout control, but don't know hot to avoid it.

Here's my code:

**1. start.java**

Part of ImageAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {            
ImageView image = new ImageView(contex);
image.setImageResource(gallery.get(position));
image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100,75)); 
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background); //here is drawable with selector
```

Part of Listener (when I delete this Listener it works)

```
public void Listen() {
gallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{text.setText("test");}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
}; }
```

**2. background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/blueback" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/redback" /> 
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the`onSelectedListener` on the individual items in the `getView()` method of `ImageAdapter` instead of setting it on the `Gallery` itself.

Secondly, is the selection still happening? I mean, is `onItemSelected()` being called? That would mean the problem is only in the selector drawing. If onItemSelected is not being called at all, you might need to do a `setClickable(true)` on the View that you return in `getView()`.